Error when trying to use addRange in Embedded Line Chart Builder
I am posting it here after trying multiple solutions.
My Data in Gsheet looks like

I am trying to draw an line Chart my code is below
var c_data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("chart_data");
var curr_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
//Inserting New Sheet here
var new_ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet('Numbers - ' + curr_date);
//Get data Range for chart here
var n_data = c_data.getRange("I2:J").getValues(); // I logged and checked here its a 2D array

var chart_d = new_ss.newChart().asLineChart().addRange(n_data)
  .setTitle("Help on the Error :(")
  .setXAxisTitle('Numbers')
  .setYAxisTitle('Months')
  .setPosition(5,5,0,0)
  .setOption('width', 700)
  .setOption('height', 200)
  .build();
 

I am getting the Error

Error
Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.EmbeddedLineChartBuilder.addRange.


The argument to addRange is a cell range. Not the cell value.
I made two changes, including the format of the graph.
  var c_data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("chart_data");
  var curr_date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  //Inserting New Sheet here
  var new_ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet('Numbers - ' + curr_date);
  //Get data Range for chart here
//>>>>_1
  // var n_data = c_data.getRange("I2:J").getValues(); // I logged and checked here its a 2D array
  var n_data = c_data.getRange("I2:J"); // I logged and checked here its a 2D array
//<<<<_1
  var chart_d = new_ss.newChart().asLineChart().addRange(n_data)
    .setTitle("Help on the Error :(")
//>>>>_2
    // .setXAxisTitle('Numbers')
    // .setYAxisTitle('Months')
    .setXAxisTitle('Months')
    .setYAxisTitle('Numbers')
//<<<<_2
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .setOption('width', 700)
    .setOption('height', 200)
    .build();

  new_ss.insertChart(chart_d);

